# Populate a large list of objects with details from another list

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a large database query that returns around `100k` records into an in-memory list. I need to link a list of related employees to each record (also around `100k` records), but I'm struggling to get useable performance.

```
foreach (var detail in reportData.Details)
{
    detail.Employees = employees
      .Where(x => x.AccountingDocumentItemId == detail.AccountingDocumentItemId)
      .Select(x => x.Employee)
      .ToList();

    detail.Employee = String.Join(", ", detail.Employees);
}
```

The above code takes over **8 minutes** to complete. I've narrowed down the speed issue to the first line in the `for loop` where it finds the related employees. If I leave out the `ToList()` it's super fast, but then the next line immediately causes the issues where the `String.Join` causes the Where to execute.

I'm obviously approaching this from the wrong angle, but I've exhausted the options I think would work.

Comment: _in-memory list_  - in this case the performace almost scales with your cores `Parallel.Foreach()`

Comment: Without the call to `ToList` all you have is a declaration which is obviously fast. If calling `ToList` takes that long I suspect the database is at fault.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Both lists are already in memory so no db queries, and the parallel foreach does not seem to have a significant effect. Looks like it could be more related to the answer from Dmitry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You current code has `O(n ** 2)` time complexity (*nested loops*) and thus you have `1e5 * 1e5 ~ 1e10` (*10 billions*) operations to perform which takes `8` minutes to complete.

Let's extract a *dictionary* in order to have `O(n)` time complexity (`~1e5` operations only):

```
var dict = reportData
  .Details
  .GroupBy(item => item.AccountingDocumentItemId,
           item => item.Employee)
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, 
                chunk => chunk.ToList());

foreach (var detail in reportData.Details) {
  detail.Employees = dict.TryGetValue(detail.AccountingDocumentItemId, out var list) 
    ? list.ToList()        // copy of the list 
    : new List<MyClass>(); // put the right type instead of MyType

  detail.Employee = String.Join(", ", detail.Employees);
}
```

Comment: This answer is good, but I'd probably try to use `ToLookup` instead of `.ToDictionary` and get rid of `.GroupBy` and `Dictionary<key, list<T>>` structure

Comment: @Fabjan: yes, `LookUp<T>` (as well as similar hash based coollection) is an alternative.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko. Exactly the input I needed. But thanks to Fabjan as well. Went with a ILookup<Guid, string> lookup = employees.ToLookup(t => t.AccountingDocumentItemId, t => t.Employee); Less than a second to link everything up.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko great job.  I think if this has a concurrent dictionary with a parallel foreach it could speed up even more if the machine allows for it

Comment: @ICodeGorilla: since `foreach` *doesn't modify* the dictionary, there is no need in *concurrent* version of the dictionary or lookup. You may want to experiment with parallel building the dictionary as well - just add `.AsParallel()` before `.GroupBy(...)`